# How to mock the custom class in unit testing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, xunit.net

I am doing the unit testing of application service using Xunit.net.

My unit test case is not getting partially executed because of following statement:

```
StringCipher stringCipher = new StringCipher();
```

`StringCipher` is class in which I have written the logic for password encryption and decryption.

Even it goes inside the constructor of `StringCipher` class but throwing exception inside the constructor.

Please let me know how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: What exception is being thrown? Show us `StringCipher` ctor and unit test that is failing.

Comment: also which mocking library are you using?